# Condition on RecordType.Name onClick JavaScript on Custom Button in Salesforce

Tags: javascript, custom-button, account, record-type

I am trying this on my Custom JavaScript button

```
IF( '{!Account.recordtype.name}' ='First RecordType'){
     // Do Something 
 }
ELSE{
    // Do something else
 }
```

and when I click on "Check Syntax" I got this error -

> Error: Field Account.recordtype.name does not exist. Check spelling.

**Answer :**  Please correct if I am missing something/doing in wrong way in below code- to get what I want.

```
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/25.0/connection.js")}
    var recordtypeResult1 = sforce.connection.query("Select id FROM RecordType WHERE Name='First RecordType'");
    var recordType1 = recordtypeResult1.getArray("records");
    var recordtypeResult2 = sforce.connection.query("Select id FROM RecordType WHERE Name='Second RecordType'");
    var recordType2 = recordtypeResult2.getArray("records");

    if( ('{!Account.recordtypeid}'== recordType1[0].Id || '{!Account.recordtypeid}' ==recordType2[0].Id)
  {
      //DO Something
}
```

Any help or suggestions ??!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind hard-coding the record type ID:

```
if('{!Account.RecordTypeId}' == '012i0000000xC4AAAU') {
    ...
}
```

There is no simple way to use the recordtype's name in this context. (You can [query](http://www.vandeveldejan.com/creating-conditional-custom-buttons-in-salesforce-some-use-cases/) to get the ID from the name.)

Comment: Hard-coding will not work for me, but I will try using Query, Thanks :)

Comment: Please have a look at the updated Question.

Comment: @NileshMendhe You should be using `==` not `=` in your if.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a **Formula Text Field** in your Account Object (say name it RTName__c) with the formula `RecordType.Name` which can give you the **Record Type Name** for the Account record

and then you can **use the formula field** in your Custom button Javascript code..

```
IF( '{!Account.RTName__c}' == 'First RecordType'){
     // Do Something 
}
ELSE{
    // Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found 3 ways of workaround in situation like this question -

1) Accepted answer of Keith   (Query RecordType) -

2) Create Formula Field on object and use it --- (Answered by Vamsi Kirshna)

3) Make use of Custom Settings to store your RecordTypeid's there and then simply compare them like shown below :

```
 if( '{!$Setup.RecordTypeIDs__c.Account_First_RType__c}'== '{!Account.RecordTypeId}') {
     //Do Something
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

if('{Account.RecordType}' == 'ABC')  works for me on the javascript button.